# Controlling GPIO pins: One class for all pins or one class for each pin?

Tags: arm, embedded, gpio, atmel, samd21

I'm writing my first program for SAMD21 and I'm gonna create GPIO class.

I wonder if is better to create one class for all pins, such as arduino:

`pinMode(led, OUTPUT)`

or create class for each pin such as:

`led.pinMode(OUTPUT)`

How is it done in professional projects?

Comment: Your first example doesn't imply a class.   Your second example doesn't imply a class per pin.

Comment: in professional products you just set or clear or read the pins via the control registers.

Comment: The question is largely a matter of opinion, so off-topic. I have a class where each object controls a _group_ of one or more adjacent GPIO pins; so neither of your suggested options.  I even have a class that controls a group of non-adjacent pins as if they were adjacent as an abstraction.  I would not suggest that either is the one true  "professional" way - it was merely a design decision that suited the needs of my particular application domain, and has served well for many years across several products. What professionals do do is _design_; not just code.

Comment: And besides above comments consider to use proper libraries for your software environments, for example, for Linux it will be `libgpiod`.

Comment: "How is it done in professional projects?" that isn't really a relevant question. "professional projects" do things according to the requirements of the project, sometimes that is X, sometimes that is Y. And because it is your first program on the SAMD21: just explore and find out what works and doesn't in situations.